# Google colab shows error in "tutorial_deep_learning_basics.ipynb"

Tags: google-colaboratory

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
      5         print('.', end='')
      6 
----> 7 model = build_model()
      8 
      9 early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=50)
```

in build_model()

```
      5     ])
      6 
----> 7     model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
      8                   loss='mse',
      9                   metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
```

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'AdamOptimizer'

can you help resolve this?

Comment: Does my answer solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `tf.train.AdamOptimizer()` with `tf.optimizers.Adam()`